# Fetching data via two dates in php sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This dates get method to get date another page

```
$fromdate = $_GET[fromDate];//14/10/2021
$todate  = $_GET[todate];17/10/2021
$collect_Amt = $conn->query("SELECT  lvlCol_amt,lvlCol_type,lvlCol_directEarn_perct,lvlCol_directEarn_amt,lvlCol_associateId,lvlCol_collectId,lvlCol_dateTime from  `t_lvl_collect` where lvlCol_dateTime  between '$_GET[fromDate]' AND  '$_GET[todate]' AND lvlCol_associateId = $MemberId ORDER BY lvlCol_dateTime DESC");
```

but return data is 15/10/2021,15/10/2021 And 16/10/2021 
17/10/2021 not disply please
help?

Comment: You are using strings, not dates? You also are open to SQL injections. Use prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

If youe date is not in Y-m-d H:i:s format please add # before data

please check below w3school link for more ref.

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_between_date&ss=-1

so your query like

```
SELECT  lvlCol_amt,lvlCol_type,lvlCol_directEarn_perct,lvlCol_directEarn_amt,lvlCol_associateId,lvlCol_collectId,lvlCol_dateTime 
from  `t_lvl_collect` 
where lvlCol_dateTime  between **#date_1** AND  **#date_2** AND lvlCol_associateId = $MemberId ORDER BY lvlCol_dateTime DESC
```

NOTE: replace `date_1` and `date_2` with your variable. add d/m/y and m/d/y both formate will work.